# WebLOAD IDE error when trying to create new project

Tags: webloadui

I just installed WebLOAD IDE & I get following error,

"failed to register on TestTalk", this happens regardless of being on VPN or what my proxy setting are.

Thanks in advance,

Salil

Comment: Please check the IP address of TestTalk. There might be an issue with the IP address. Let me know if that helps. Thanks!